# Facing issue in Data driven testing using excel sheet in eclipse under robot framework

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

I am trying to automate login page with the help of data driven testing by excel reading but it's throwing the error. kindly help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1eJx.png)

```
*** Settings ***

Library           SeleniumLibrary

Resource    ../Resources/Login_resources.robot

Library   DataDriver  ../TestData/DDTXLS.xlsx    encoding="ISO-8859-1"

   
Library  String
      
Suite Setup  Login_resources.Start TestCase

Suite Teardown   Login_resources.Finish TestCase

Test Template   Invalid login


*** Test Cases *** 
Tc  1  3         
#Login with user    ${username}     ${password}   
   
       


*** Keywords ***

Invalid login
  
       [Arguments]         ${username}     ${password} 
   
       Input username      ${username}

       Input pass      ${password}

       Click login button

Login_resources.robot

*** Settings ***

Library      SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
 
${LOGIN URL}        http://localhost:8100/

${Browser}      chrome


*** Keywords ***

Start TestCase 
    
   Set Selenium Implicit Wait    2s

    Open Browser            ${LOGIN URL}       ${Browser}

    maximize browser window

    Select frame  removeframe

    Sleep  2
    
Finish TestCase

        close all browsers

Open login page

        go to       ${LOGIN URL}

Input username

  [Arguments]     ${username}

        input text      xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input      ${username}

Input pass

        [Arguments]     ${password}

        input text      xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input     ${password}

Click login button

        click element    xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/a
```

Output::

```
  [ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: SyntaxError: First column is not "*** Test Cases ***". This Column is mandatory.
```

Comment: As a draft guess: Try to remove the leading space in the test case row ` Tc 1 3`. It probably adds additional empty column.

Comment: I tried this but Issue is not with this.

Comment: You'd probably want to format this question better too...

Comment: I am getting below error message even i am already declared the test cases in the excel sheet. "[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: SyntaxError: First column is not "*** Test Cases ***". This Column is mandatory.
"

Comment: something is missing in the excel sheet that's why it's showing this error but i dont know what is exactly missing

Comment: Draft guess to check: taking a look into the screenshot we could see the first column in your excel file actually is not called `*** Test Cases ***` like the error said. It is actually with an extra semicolon char in the end `... ***;`!  I'm not sure but try to remove semicolon `;` from all the cells. It probably makes all your values incorrect

Comment: initially i tried without semicolon but same result is showing so i am trying with other possibilities but didn't get success. i saw a csv format where they used semicolon so that i tried. if you have any idea please suggest

Comment: So, the file `DDTXLS` is actually excel or csv? 
Could it be that you passed wrong format to DataDriver? I would suggest to try different option from [File Encoding and CSV Dialect](https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#file-encoding-and-csv-dialect)

Comment: DDTXLS is excel file. i already tried the same with csv and that time it works perfectly fine.